# Combining multiple Excel rows based on similar contents then incrementing a column in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to set-up a VBA routine that will check all the rows of a worksheet and then combine two rows that are identical, then once it does that increment the "QTY" column.

Below is a before and after example of what I'm looking to achieve.

---

Before:
[image: before]

---

After: 
[image: after]

---

I've tried applying a few solutions I've found around Superuser and various places on the internet, but unfortunately nothing directly applies to this and my limited understanding of VBA in Excel is hampering me from getting around this matter.

Comment: You need to share your code as well please, so we can see what you're trying and where it is going wrong.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the situation for which Data Consolidation is for? IMHO no need to program anything, it's included in XL, and fast.

Comment: I have two reasons for omitting the use of Data Consolidation.  First is being that I couldn't quite get it to work on my end for this particular set-up, possibly because I have a header on this file.  Second is that this was for a customer and I wanted to make the process as simple as possible for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code in a module, before using it change the variable *qtycolumn* to the number of the column where you have your **QTY** title:

```
Sub customgroup()
    Dim a As Application
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set a = Application
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    wks.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    qtycolumn = 4 'this have to be changed to the QTY column
    reviewing = True
    visitrow = 1
    While reviewing = True
        visitrow = visitrow + 1
        If wks.Cells(visitrow, 1) = "" Then
            reviewing = False
        End If
        If wks.Cells(visitrow, qtycolumn) <> 0 Then
            countitems = 1
            visitrow2 = visitrow + 1
            reviewing2 = reviewing
            While reviewing2 = True
                If wks.Cells(visitrow2, 1) = "" Then
                    reviewing2 = False
                End If
                If wks.Cells(visitrow2, qtycolumn) <> 0 Then
                    compareranges = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(wks.Rows(visitrow).Value)), Chr(0)) = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(wks.Rows(visitrow2).Value)), Chr(0))
                    If compareranges = True Then
                        countitems = countitems + wks.Cells(visitrow2, qtycolumn)
                        wks.Cells(visitrow2, qtycolumn) = 0
                    End If
                End If
                visitrow2 = visitrow2 + 1
            Wend
            wks.Cells(visitrow, qtycolumn) = countitems
        End If
    Wend
    visitrow = visitrow - 1
    LastColumn = wks.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    Set DataRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(visitrow, LastColumn))
    lettercolumn = Split(Cells(, qtycolumn).Address, "$")(1)
    DataRange.Sort key1:=Range(lettercolumn & ":" & lettercolumn), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    For i = visitrow To 2 Step -1
        filterqty = wks.Cells(i, qtycolumn)
        If filterqty = 0 Then
            wks.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
   wks.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to make a minor change to the "For" statement changing the "To 2" to "To 5" to account for a header I forgot to show in my screenshot, but this works great!  Thanks again!